# No longer able to access FlexTable elements on callback

Tags: google-apps-script

The best example for what is happening is [demonstrated here](https://sites.google.com/site/appsscripttutorial/miscellaneous/creating-form-elements-dynamically-using-google-apps-script-gas). My code is very, very similar to what is used in that link (I based mine off of it).

Load up that site and click the '+' button on the right hand side. You will get an error that states "Error encountered: Cannot convert NaN to ."

I've narrowed the problem to the _addRemoveRow function. It seems like something changed recently with how accessing FlexTable properties is done on callbacks. My code and the site I linked were working fine last night. Today, I get the error.

I looked to see if there were any changelog/release notes that could explain this, but came up empty handed.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the issue you are experiencing is more likely related to the TAG value as [described in my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875398/how-to-use-tags-on-widgets-without-names-in-gas-ui) with an example test code.

It happened +-10 hours ago, we should raise an issue on [the issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list) as Henrique suggested, I planned to do it if no other comments come in the next few hours but if it's really annoying for you please consider to do it sooner ;-)

Comment: I read through your question, and it definitely does sound like what I'm going through as well.