# GAS - setTag() - getTag() still not working

Tags: tags, google-apps-script

I'm creating a webapp which allow :

- to log using data stored in a spreadsheet (login and password)
- to add some data to this spreadsheet (bet on rubgy matchs)

My problem is to recognize which user is connected.

What i did so far
in the doGet function, where all panels except connection are invisible, I created a label where i'll store the login into the tag

```
var loginlabel=app.createLabel().setId('loginlabel').setText('test').setVisible(true);
```

in the connection, I store the login into a invisible label tag

```
var logintest=e.parameter.logint;
app.getElementById('loginlabel').setTag(logintest);
```

I want to allow people to change their own password (but I also need to retrieve the login name for other purposes, but let's take this one

When I click on "Modify password" button,  I want to get the Tag, but I always get a NULL

```
var login=app.getElementById('loginlabel').getTag();
```

I'm free to share my code here or wherever

Maybe it does exist other way to do this, I'm open for advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a server handler you can get the tag value using

```
var tagValue = e.parameter.loginlabel_tag ; // assuming the label has a name = 'loginlabel'
```

Note that the widget must have a name to be able to retrieve the tag value (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875398/how-to-use-tags-on-widgets-without-names-in-gas-ui) among [others](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5DsetTag))